# Upgrade ext.net V1.x to ext.net V2.x

Tags: extjs, ext.net

There are lot of changes in ext.net tool V1.2 and V2.2.

I try to upgrade my application but not easy to find these changes.

I use 
http://examples.ext.net/
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/

Any other help available for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best thoughts regarding migration from v1 to v2 are [here](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?18358-CLOSED-Update-version-1-3-as-2-0&p=79239&viewfull=1#post79239).